# Django-South introspection rule doesn't work

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

I'm using `Django 1.2.3` and `South 0.7.3`.

I am trying to convert my app (named `core`) to use *Django-South*. I have a custom model/field that I'm using, named `ImageWithThumbsField`. It's basically just the ol' `django.db.models.ImageField` with some attributes such as height, weight, etc.

While trying to `./manage.py convert_to_auth core` I receieve South's *freezing* errors. I have no idea why, I'm Probably missing something...

I am using a simple custom Model:

```
from django.db.models import ImageField

class ImageWithThumbsField(ImageField):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, width_field=None, height_field=None, sizes=None, **kwargs):
        self.verbose_name=verbose_name
        self.name=name
        self.width_field=width_field
        self.height_field=height_field
        self.sizes = sizes
        super(ImageField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

And this is my introspection rule, which I add to the top of my `models.py`:

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
from lib.thumbs import ImageWithThumbsField

add_introspection_rules(
    [
        (
            (ImageWithThumbsField, ),
            [],
            {
                "verbose_name": ["verbose_name", {"default": None}],
                "name":         ["name",         {"default": None}],
                "width_field":  ["width_field",  {"default": None}],
                "height_field": ["height_field", {"default": None}],
                "sizes":        ["sizes",        {"default": None}],
            },
        ),
    ],
    ["^core/.fields/.ImageWithThumbsField",])
```

This is the errors I receieve:

```
! Cannot freeze field 'core.additionalmaterialphoto.photo'
! (this field has class lib.thumbs.ImageWithThumbsField)
! Cannot freeze field 'core.material.photo'
! (this field has class lib.thumbs.ImageWithThumbsField)
! Cannot freeze field 'core.material.formulaimage'
! (this field has class lib.thumbs.ImageWithThumbsField)

! South cannot introspect some fields; this is probably because they are custom
! fields. If they worked in 0.6 or below, this is because we have removed the
! models parser (it often broke things).
! To fix this, read http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/MyFieldsDontWork
```

Does anybody know why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got it! :)

I changed this: `["^core/.fields/.ImageWithThumbsField",]`

To this: `["^lib\.thumbs\.ImageWithThumbsField",]`

This whole line is a *regular-expression* of python paths of **Django field types** (read this again, long sentence).

*South* stumbled upon a field name `ImageWithThumbsField` that was declared in the path `lib.thumbs`. I gave him a wrong path, so South *still* didn't know what to do when stumbling upon this field.

Once I gave him the correct path, it knew how to handle the field once he got to it.

Comment: Can't accept the answer yet, http://StackOverflow.com says I need to wait 2 days before doing so.

Comment: Probably this question is too specific for it to get much attention, but just know you saved my day. I'd take hours to reach the solution, and this totally did the trick. Just as a sidenote, what worked for me was ["^myapp.thumbs.ImageWithThumbsField",] as my thumbs.py is inside the myapp dir. Cheers!

Comment: It should actually be `["^lib\.thumbs\.ImageWithThumbsField",])`. The dot "." has a particular meaning in regular expressions so you have to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: i used @exfizik format and it works. the important thing is to get the correct FULL path! thanks.